# Trying to build a simple calculator in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to build a simple addition calculator in `CodeIgniter`. I am trying to get value from the post method into my controller. While executing the code, I'm getting an error saying

> undefined index: number1

My controller file:

```
public function addQuote(){
     if(isset($_POST['adds'])){
         $ans=$_POST['number1'] + $_POST['number2'];
         $data= array( 
             'number1'=> $_POST['number1'],
             'number2'=> $_POST['number2'],
             'ans'=> $ans
         );
     } else{
             $data = array(

                 'number1'=> "0",
                 'number2'=> "0",
                 'ans'=> '0'
                  );
         }


     $this->load->view('addQuote',$data);
```

My view file is here:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-4 well">
                <h2> Addition of two numbers</h2>
                <form action="<?php echo base_url(''); ?>welcome/addQuote" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="number1"> Enter number 1</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number1" placeholder="Enter number 1" value="<?php $number1;?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="number2"> Enter Number</label>
                        <input typle="number" class="form-control" id="number2" placeholder="Enter number 2"  value="<?php $number2;?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="ans"> Answer</label>
                        <p class="text-success"><?= $ans; ?> </p>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="adds" > submit</button>
```

Comment: Please mention name in input type

Comment: <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number1" placeholder="Enter number 1" name ="number1" value="<?php $number1;?>">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `name` attribute to your elements.

As only elements are submitted with `name` attribute added.

`id` and `class` are mainly for CSS and JS purposes.

So,

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="number1" placeholder="Enter number 1" value="<?php $number1;?>">
```

Should be:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="number1" placeholder="Enter number 1" value="<?php $number1;?>" name="number1">
```

Observe the added `name` attribute.

Same for `number2`

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="number1" placeholder="Enter number 1" value="<?php $number1;?>" name="number1">

<input type="number" class="form-control" id="number2" placeholder="Enter number 1" value="<?php $number2;?>" name="number2">

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="adds" > submit</button>
```

Comment: MoazAlawiaty, you have posted correct answer, but, without proper explanation, how do the user will know what went wrong exactly?